# Где рисовать в WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, графика

Я написал в функции `WndProc()` под `case WM_PAINT:` алгоритм, по которому программа должна рисовать.

У данного места есть существенный недостаток — он рисует только когда меняется положение или размер окна. А мне нужно, чтобы рисовалось при нажатии на кнопку. то есть кнопка должна вызывать эту функцию. Я написал функцию, и вызвал её при нажатии на кнопку. Прототип функции выглядит так:

```
paint(PAINTSTRUCT &ps, HWND &hWnd);
```

Но эта функция ничего не отображает.

Подозреваю, что не рисует, так как в `case WM_PAINT:` уже рисуется. Скажите, пожалуйста, можно как нибудь исключить этот конфликт?

Comment: @VladD, еху!! спасибо, то, что нужно!!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`InvalidateRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002.aspx) не пробовали?

Comment: отлично, рад, что помогло! :-)